# Ruby on Rails issue/bug reporting gem

Tags: rubygems, jira, bug-reporting

I trying to find a gem for Ruby on Rails to allow my clients to report bugs, similar to [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira). Everywhere I search, I only see the bug reporting side of various gems, not a gem for reporting bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)

Redmine is a flexible project management web application. Written using the Ruby on Rails framework, it is cross-platform and cross-database.